# SwiftUI How to add action on UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, swiftui, uinavigationitem

I am using SwiftUI and I have added Button in NavigationBar but I am unable to set action on that button. I tried these two approaches but failed.

**Approach:1**

```
.navigationBarTitle("\(task.label)")
.navigationBarItems(trailing: UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.actionName)))
```

But I am having this error here

> Argument type 'UIBarButtonItem' does not conform to expected type
>   'View'

**Approach:2**

```
.navigationBarTitle("\(task.label)")
.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationBarButtonItem())

struct NavigationBarButtonItem : View {
    var body : some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Button Tapped")
        }, label: {Text("Done")})
    }
}
```

Over here, This print statements never runs, although Button "Done" shows on Right side of NavigationBar, but action never works.

Answer (score 1):

> .navigationBarItems(trailing: UIBarButtonItem(...

the above is definitely incorrect - you try to pass UIKit object instead of expected View struct

The following one definitely works (tested with Xcode 11.2+)

```
NavigationView {
    // ... some view is here
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done") { 
       print("Done something")
    })
}
```

Well, copy-pasted "as is" your code from **Approach 2** works as well, so probably the reason is not in this code.

It is not provided all your code, but I can suppose you placed it *outside* `NavigationView`, but doc says:

> ```
> /// This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible
> /// within a `NavigationView`.
> ```